# floating a div causing image to align itself at the center of page

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have this funny thing going on with my html code. I am using divs instead of a table, it  has a left and a right side. Images are placed on the left and text on the right. 
     The funny thing is that the first row behaves just fine but the second row image floats in the middle of the page.
         Here is my jsbin link http://jsbin.com/alejuHE/1/ 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this is to clear your floats after each line, I updated your jsbin to demonstrate this http://jsbin.com/alejuHE/7/

This solution makes use of `clear:both;` to effectively reset your float after each line, meaning the image moves back to the left instead of floating on the previous one.

However, depending on your application I would say that using floats in this way isn't preferable, you should consider using containing elements that are set to `display:block;` to make your content flow down the page correctly.